# What is the purpose of the TDG gate in QISKit?

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

The QISKIT documentation doesn't explain what a TDG gate does and I can't find it anywhere else online.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [QISKit documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_autodoc/qiskit._compositegate.html#qiskit._compositegate.CompositeGate.tdg), `tdg(q)` applies the `Tdg` gate to a qubit.

$T$ is the basically the [$\pi/8$ phase shift gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Phase_shift_(%7F'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-0000002D-QINU%60%22'%7F)_gates) whose matrix representation considering standard (computational) basis is:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\pi/4}\end{matrix}\right)$$

`Tdg` is simply the [conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) of the matrix $T$ i.e. $T^{\dagger}$, which is:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-i\pi/4}\end{matrix}\right)$$

Thus, the $T$ gate would map the [basis vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) (of a qubit) $|0\rangle$ to $|0\rangle$ itself and $|1\rangle$ to $e^{i\pi/4}|1\rangle$, whereas $T^{\dagger}$ would map $|0\rangle$ to $|0\rangle$ itself and $|1\rangle$ to $e^{-i\pi/4}|1\rangle$.

**P.S:** In case you're wondering what `dg` means in `tdg`, it is simply an abbreviation for "dagger" i.e. in the sense of $T^{\dagger}$ (pronounced as $T$ - dagger).

Comment: No answers since July, Blue?

Comment: @John Yeah, I was kinda busy with university work in the past few months. I'm also focusing a bit more on theoretical computer science rather than quantum computing these days. I will perhaps resume answering when my vacations begin. Have a good day/night.